# How to change list items size by using checkbox with Android?

Tags: android

Can anyone show me how to use checkbox to change items size in listview in Android?

When the checkbox is unchecked ,the items in listview is normal size.

When the checkbox is checked, all items in the listview will enlarged.

code or tips will help ,thanks

Comment: First you check the checkbox value. If the checkbox.ischeck value true then change the sizes of listview items programatically or else do your stuff..

Comment: Your Code and Your Tips Will help us too Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is for checking and setting listview item size in getview of adapter according to checkbox state.

```
if(!isChecked)
{
   convertView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(NormalWidth,  
    Normalheight));
}
else
{
 convertView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(EnlargeWidth,  
    Enlargeheight));
}
```

and for checkbox checked change you may write like as below:

```
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
{
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   /* this line will Refress the listview so you can change the value of isChecked variable then it will change the size of listview item.*/
}
});
```